# Alternative to <%= in Ruby On Rails view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I was wandering if there is an equivalent to `<%=` in a Ruby on Rails view using `<%` and `%>`.

PHP allows the use of `<?=$str ?>` and `<? echo $str ?>`, do views in RoR allow something like this? Doing `<%=` in a large block of Ruby On Rails code in a view isn't very nice to see, not to mention a nuisance when doing something like for loops. Is it possible?

Comment: wait, you don't like `<%=` but do like `<%` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't Ruby On Rails construction, that's construction of ERB template engine. If you like, you can use [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) or any other template engine. [This](http://www.hokstad.com/mini-reviews-of-19-ruby-template-engines.html) is rather old, but interesting review many of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about *.html.erb files.  Try something else.  For instance, HAML.  http://haml-lang.com/